# Service Provider and Identity Providers lists do not show changes in cluster node with WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Two Identity Server cluster nodes, running 5.0.0, have been created. When an IdP or SP is created on the first node, the second node does not see the entry until an IdP or SP is added on that node. It then properly displays the correct entries. Clicking on the "list" option to refresh will not show the entries.

The Identity Server nodes are running on RHEL6 with the backend database pointing to Microsoft SQL Server and user repository against Active Directory.

Comment: Did you share the identity database with two nodes ?. And have you applied the service pack available [1] here.
[1] http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/

Comment: The database is shared which is why the lists will eventually get updated correctly. It does look like it was a patch / update problem. We work with Ellucian for deploying the product and after the update everything was working as expected. Thanks @Ishara

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by installing the latest service pack from http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/